# full screen background image with vstack

Tags: swiftui, vstack

i want to have a full screen background image with a navigationview (must be on top because it is from the basis view and not in "this" view normally).
In this view i want a VStack which is just inside the secure area, so between navigationbar and bottom layout.

unfortunately i got (see picture)

I expected the texts inside...[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {

                Image("laguna")
                    .resizable()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Text("just a test")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    Spacer()
                    Text ("not centered....why?")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)

                }
                .zIndex(4)
                .navigationBarTitle("nav bar title")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a bit modified variant. Tested with Xcode 11.4 (finally released) / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

```
struct TestFullScreenImage: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Image("large_image")
                    .resizable()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .scaledToFill()

                VStack {
                    Text("Just a test")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        Spacer()
                    Text("centered")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .background(Color.green)
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Navigation Title")
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

Comment: Users suggested flagging as one of the two questions as duplicate. Either this question or https://stackoverflow.com/q/57649369. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

If need to use `NavigationView`, and maintain the image's aspect ratio, you can do this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct FullScreenPictureDemo: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Image("your_full_screen_background_picture")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .scaledToFill()
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```